# Not able to load *.Rda file from GitHub in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R. I have downloaded a dataset. But I am not able to load it.

```
file_url<-"https://github.com/TarekDib03/ExploratoryDataAnalysisCoursera/blob/master/maacs.Rda"
download.file(file_url,"macs.rda")
load("macs.rda")
```

Error:

```
Error in load("macs.rda") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘maacs.Rda’ has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Comment: I believe the file is not valid any more

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `?raw=true` to your `file_url` and then load it inside [`url()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html):

```
file_url <- "https://github.com/TarekDib03/ExploratoryDataAnalysisCoursera/blob/master/maacs.Rda?raw=true"
load(url(file_url))
```

If you want to download that file to your computer, do that from your [browser](https://github.com/TarekDib03/ExploratoryDataAnalysisCoursera/blob/master/maacs.Rda?raw=true), otherwise it will not work.

Hope this helps.